# Is there a clustering algorithm for my specific situation?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

This is a scatterplot of my data:
[image]

In my opinion, I see two clusters here. A large, wide, highly dense one up top, and a smaller, lower density one in the bottom right:
[image]

When I do k-means clustering, the data ends up getting split right down the middle:
[image]

**My question:** Is there a clustering algorithm out there that would be able to discern the clusters that I am seeing/describing?

Comment: Let me know if there is a better way to phrase this question. I would like the question to be useful to people with a similar problem as me.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you seek recommendations for statistical methods for clustering, then you should ask such questions over at [stats.se] instead. You are more likely to get better answers there.

Comment: k-means will always result in a linear separation of the clusters. You may want to have a look at gaussian mixture models, but really it all depends on what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any code or data here.  Anyway, I'd recommend DBSCAN, Affinity Propagation, and you can try GMM as well.  You can find some sample code below.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#dbscan

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#affinity-propagation

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/mixture.html#mixture

```
print(__doc__)

import numpy as np

from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler


# #############################################################################
# Generate sample data
centers = [[1, 1], [-1, -1], [1, -1]]
X, labels_true = make_blobs(n_samples=750, centers=centers, cluster_std=0.4,
                            random_state=0)

X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)

# #############################################################################
# Compute DBSCAN
db = DBSCAN(eps=0.3, min_samples=10).fit(X)
core_samples_mask = np.zeros_like(db.labels_, dtype=bool)
core_samples_mask[db.core_sample_indices_] = True
labels = db.labels_

# Number of clusters in labels, ignoring noise if present.
n_clusters_ = len(set(labels)) - (1 if -1 in labels else 0)
n_noise_ = list(labels).count(-1)

print('Estimated number of clusters: %d' % n_clusters_)
print('Estimated number of noise points: %d' % n_noise_)
print("Homogeneity: %0.3f" % metrics.homogeneity_score(labels_true, labels))
print("Completeness: %0.3f" % metrics.completeness_score(labels_true, labels))
print("V-measure: %0.3f" % metrics.v_measure_score(labels_true, labels))
print("Adjusted Rand Index: %0.3f"
      % metrics.adjusted_rand_score(labels_true, labels))
print("Adjusted Mutual Information: %0.3f"
      % metrics.adjusted_mutual_info_score(labels_true, labels))
print("Silhouette Coefficient: %0.3f"
      % metrics.silhouette_score(X, labels))

# #############################################################################
# Plot result
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Black removed and is used for noise instead.
unique_labels = set(labels)
colors = [plt.cm.Spectral(each)
          for each in np.linspace(0, 1, len(unique_labels))]
for k, col in zip(unique_labels, colors):
    if k == -1:
        # Black used for noise.
        col = [0, 0, 0, 1]

    class_member_mask = (labels == k)

    xy = X[class_member_mask & core_samples_mask]
    plt.plot(xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1], 'o', markerfacecolor=tuple(col),
             markeredgecolor='k', markersize=14)

    xy = X[class_member_mask & ~core_samples_mask]
    plt.plot(xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1], 'o', markerfacecolor=tuple(col),
             markeredgecolor='k', markersize=6)

plt.title('Estimated number of clusters: %d' % n_clusters_)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I dont see how this would work for the question posted above, in your example using DBSCAN there are clearly 3 very dense regions. Thus, the algorithm can find the most dense regions of the data and start the algorithm with the distance(eps param) parameter and very easily group the information. If you could please help me understand why OP could use this algorithm in a dataset where there is only one clear group , and he would have to specify two different eps parameters.

Comment: What?!  This is an example.  Obviously the OP has to feed in his own data.  With no data posted and no code shared, I am suggesting three options that can be attempted.  Run an experiment and see what the outcome is.  If this doesn't work, try something else.  If that doesn't work, try something completely different.